# German SE has launched: What about its design and logo?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I've received an e-mail saying that the commitment for the German StackExchange was fulfilled. I was wondering, what design and logo is this site going to have? How does it work? I mean, the creator and the mods decide it, or we all decide it together?

Apart from the fact that this question is listed in the [The 7 Essential questions of every meta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), I think that a good design is part of the success for a StackExchange site, you can see other SE sites to see it...

Comment: Time to revisit this one.

Comment: as @MrLister already realized: is there new relevance due to "not beta any longer"? [Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: This question is and the links therein are horribly outdated. If you want to work on this, I strongly suggest that you start a new discussion from scratch.

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from last week: [Custom German Language design and logo - Information gathering](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1697/8844) :)

Comment: Update: [New site design launched](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1752/8844)

Answer (score 6):

It's going to be a while before this site receives its own design. Just because *you* have fulfilled your commitment doesn't mean the site is out of beta or has even received the permanent stamp of approval. It'll be in public beta for 3 months before that's going to happen. When the time comes, the design will be somewhat of a community process. Peruse the other beta meta sites to get a feeling for it. :)

Comment: Ah ok, I just asked because this is my first fulfilled commitment, I don't know how it works lol... So that "fulfilled" regards me only? How will I know when the site launches for everyone? Thanks for the answer, Deceze. :)

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, fulfillment only concerns your personal vow to participate in this site during beta. I believe you'll receive email about the further beta/public development of this site, but you can always follow it here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language-usage

Comment: Still, doesn't this mean we should slowly start thinking about the site's design? There's also still the [font issue](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/56/font-bug-main-site-font-renders-german-closing-quotation-marks-wrongly)...

Comment: @fzwo: It's going to be in beta for a long while first. There's a lot of [betas](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) and not that many [launched sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched).

Comment: Content over presentation; it is more important to build up a good site with good questions/answers and rules first before even thinking about the design. If we were to decide about the design now, we would just disregard the content.

Comment: @poke But there is no harm in having a thread where people can dump ideas.

Comment: I saw https://diy.stackexchange.com/ leaving beta status. I think it is done by some professionals. BTW [I asked a similar question for the Database Administrators site](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/which-color-to-chose-for-the-dba-exchange-site). It doesn't seem to be our problem

Answer (score 1):

Nachdem German Stackexchange die Beta-Phase hinter sich gelassen hat, wird diese vor acht Jahren gestellte Frage schön langsam wieder aktuell.

Was die Gestaltung eines Logos betrifft, möchte ich sehr davor warnen, denselben Fehler zu machen, den man so oft auf diversen Seiten im Internet sieht: Da werden nämlich sehr oft Flaggen von Nationalstaaten verwendet, um Sprachen zu symbolisieren. Die Verbreitungsgebiete von Sprachen stimmen aber in keinem einzigen Fall mit den Territorien von Nationalstaaten überein.

Insbesondere wird Deutsch außer in Deutschland z.B. auch noch in Österreich, der Schweiz, Liechtenstein und Italien (Südtirol) gesprochen. Daher darf meiner Meinung nach das zukünftige Logo von German.Stackexchange keine Farbkombination enthalten, die an irgend eine Flagge eines Staates erinnert. Es darf auch sonst keine Symbole enthalten, die für etwas anderes typisch sind als für die deutsche Sprache.

Ich habe aber auch zwei konstruktive Vorschläge, nämlich diese beiden:

[image: ä]
und

[image: ß]

Das Zeichen *ä* findet man (wie alle Umlaute) zwar auch in anderen Sprachen (z.B. Finnisch), aber es wird soviel ich weiß vor allem im englischsprachigen Raum als typisch Deutsch wahrgenommen. Von den drei Umlauten fällt meine Wahl auf das *ä* weil ich finde, dass es schöner aussieht als *ö* und *ü*, und weil es im Alphabet vor seinen beiden Geschwistern steht.

Das *ß* gibt es hingegen wirklich nur im deutschen Alphabet, aber leider nur im deutschen und im österreichischen Deutsch. Im schweizerischen Deutsch, das Amtssprache in der Schweiz und in Liechtenstein ist, gibt es dieses Zeichen nicht. Außerdem ist dieses Zeichen im englischsprachigen Raum eher weniger bekannt, und wenn, dann wird es für ein großes B gehalten (»German B«). Daher ist für mich *ß* die zweite Wahl.

Comment: Diese Frage ist veraltet. Aktuell wird die Diskussion über das Logo hier geführt: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1516/bedarf-w%c3%bcnsche-vorschl%c3%a4ge-an-ein-neues-logo-f%c3%bcr-german-se

Comment: Gegenbeispiel: [Japanisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanische_Sprache) wird nur in Japan und von Auswandern, die in den letzten zwei Jahrhunderten Japan verlassen haben, gesprochen. Die Grenzen des Nationalstaates sind aber auch Seegrenzen, das macht es einfacher.