# Moderatorenwahl / moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, community-moderation

Bezugnehmend auf [diese Ankündigung](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1503/581) habe ich mich gefragt, ob bereits ein Zeitplan für die Moderatorenwahl existiert und was dies bspw. für die aktuellen *Moderatoren auf Zeit* bedeutet?

In regards to [this announcement](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1503/581) I was wondering if there was already a schedule for the moderator election and what  it means for the *moderators pro tem(pore)*?

Comment: And an additional comment vaguely citing a CM: The election process is currently still very “hands-on” for the CMs, so starting the elections for all sites in one big swoop is not manageable.

Comment: Gibt es irgendwo eine Stelle, wo (Moderatoren-)Wahlen beschrieben sind (nein, ich will mich nicht bewerben). Ich hatte schon früher gesucht, aber ich habe nur einen Link bei den Badges "Caucus" und "Constituent" gefunden https://german.stackexchange.com/election , aber der erklärt leider nicht, was es damit auf sich hat, sondern sagt nur, dass es aktuelle keine Wahlen gibt.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf klassisch wird auf [das](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) und [das](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) verwiesen. Ansonsten auch die [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) ...

Answer (score 6):

Nein, die gibt es noch nicht. Alles was wir jetzt wissen, steht [in der Ankündigung](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/295232):

> The sites that qualify will:
>
> ...
>
> - have their full-site elections delayed, but scheduled eventually

Im moment gibt es noch neue Pro-Tempore Wahlen, z.B. auf [die spanische Seite](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3123/13538). Normalerweise, wenn eine Seite 'voll' wird, dann gibt es [ein Wahl für *alle* Moderatorpositionen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/295232); die aktuelle Moderatoren müssen sich auch dafür nominieren (wenn sie das wollen, natürlich).

---

No, there is no schedule yet. All that we know is [in the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/295232):

> The sites that qualify will:
>
> ...
>
> - have their full-site elections delayed, but scheduled eventually

At the moment there are still new Pro-Tempore Elections, e.g. [on the Spanish site](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3123/13538). Normally, when a site graduates, there is [an election for *all* moderator positions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/295232); the current moderators must nominate themselves too (if they want, of course).

Comment: Nur zur Bestätigung: Wir Moderatoren wissen auch nicht mehr als dies.