# Nicht mehr "Beta". Was heißt das?

Tags: discussion

Die Stackexchange-Site "German Language" hat vor zwei Wochen ihren Beta-Status abgelegt. Siehe [Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta)

Der Zusatz "Beta" ist jetzt weg und *German Language* steht jetzt gemeinsam mit *Lego, Windows Phone* und *Poker* in der [Liste der gelaunchten Sites](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched). So what? Ändert sich sonst was? Wenn ja: Was ist jetzt anders?

Answer (score 7):

Bis zu einer [Moderatorenwahl](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1509) ist die Änderung überwiegend kosmetischer Natur. Sie ist aber nicht unwichtig:

- Neue Besucher erhalten nicht mehr den Eindruck, dass es sich bei unserer Seite um einen im Aufbau befindlichen Testballon handelt.
- Man muss nicht erst mit der Stack-Exchange-Politik vertraut sein, um zu wissen, dass diese Seite auf ewig ausgelegt ist.
- Wir sind offiziell als vollwertige Seite anerkannt.
- Die obigen Punkte heben die Moral und Motivation, langfristige Verbesserungen der Seite anzustreben.

Siehe auch [diese Anfrage auf Meta SE](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1744).

---

Ganz am Rande gibt es dann noch eine nicht-kosmetische Änderung, nämlich dass ohne Kommentar geschlossene Fragen nicht mehr zu einer automatischen Flagge führen.

Comment: Kriegen wir dann auch ein eigenes Icon? (total wichtige Frage...)

Comment: @miep: Ein nicht-sprechblasenbasiertes Log kommt wahrscheinlich erst mit dem eigenen Design für den Rest der Seite. Was wir machen können, ist ein sprechblasenbasiertes Logo mit etwas anderem als *DE* darin (zum Beispiel ein Fraktur-ß). Zum Beispiel [Spanish Language SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) oder [Buddhism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/) haben so etwas. Du kannst ruhig eine eigene Meta-Diskussion hierzu starten.

Comment: Umlautbuchstaben sind meines Erachtens (zumindest außerhalb des deutschsprachigen Raumes) repräsentativer das Eszett. Da kann man sich überlegen, wem widmet man diese Seite. Aber vielleicht ein schönes Eszett verlockt auch Klientel.

Comment: @c.p.: Das war nur ein Beispiel. Die Diskussion gehört wirklich in eine eigene Frage.

Comment: „Bis zu einer Moderatorenwahl“: Sind die aktuellen Moderatoren (sind das alle und ausschließlich die user mit Raute?) nicht gewählt (sondern von der Hauptseite aus eingesetzt)?

Comment: @Philipp: Ja, wir sind von Stack Exchange (nicht wirklich die Hauptseite, sondern der Betreiber) ernannt.

Comment: @miep & Wrzlprmft: dazu gibt es schon eine Meta-Frage, nämlich als die public beta begann: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/178/36160