# Bedarf / Wünsche / Vorschläge an ein neues Logo für German.SE?

Tags: discussion, design

Mit dem Paradigmen-Wechsel bei SE hat German.SE den Beta-Status "über Nacht" [verlassen](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1503/36160).

Beim Wechsel in die Public Beta gab es [die Frage nach dem Logo](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/178/36160) bereits.

[Die Frage nach funktionellen Konsequenzen](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/36160) des neuen Status enthält den Hinweis auf kosmetische Änderungen - angeschlossen der Augenzwinker-Kommentar von [miep](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/users/35636/miep), ob dann auch ein neues Logo bei rum kommt.

Daher nun als eigenständige **Frage 1**: Neues Logo fällig/ gewünscht/ gebraucht?

[Einen Hinweis](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/german/img/apple-touch-icon.png) gibt es auf Meta:

> Phase 2
> Then, as it becomes available:
>
> the site gets their custom design

**Frage 2:** Inwiefern ist die German.SE-Community per Planung darin eingebunden?

- Edit: Rückmeldung zum Prozess
- Wrzlprmft hat SE [angeschrieben](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1532/36160)(= Antwort unten) und es war damals (September 2019) ungeklärt, inwieweit wir als Community mitreden können.

**Status quo:**

[image: aktuelles German.SE-Logo]

PS: Hilfreiche Links zum Prozess / übersehene Infos gerne gesehen.

**Edit: Hinweis von Catija**

Unter dem Vorschlag von [Wrzlprmft](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1522/36160) hat [Catija](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33667/catija) (bei SE angestellt) kommentiert, dass

- das Logo eindeutig sein solle
- es von Vorteil - nicht Bedingung - ist, wenn es Unicode-Zeichen im selben Font wie bei "den anderen" Seiten sind (also da wo es nur Buchstaben sind)
- aus den bestehenden alten Logos nicht auf die Regeln für neue Logos geschlossen werden darf

Comment: Welche Anforderungen bzgl Größe, Auflösung, Skalierung, etc gibt es denn? Also in welchen Größen wird es benötigt und muss dann gut aussehen + erkennbar sein?

Comment: In einem der Kommentare unten wird behauptet, dass die blaue Sprechblase bleiben muss und nur über den Inhalt entschieden werden kann. Stimmt das? Wenn ja, dann ist das ziemlich ... doof. Die gleichen sich dadurch wie ein [Ei dem anderen](https://stackexchange.com/sites#).

Comment: Übrigens: wird das nach dem Ergebnis dieser Antworten gewählt? Oder soll diese Frage schlicht Vorschläge motivieren? (Würde auch ein Esszet gewinnen [dessen Entwurf wegen der Schweiß ich schon gelöscht habe], so würde das System das akzeptieren?)

Comment: @c.p.: diese Unbekannte habe ich am Ende der Frage als "Frage 2" getarnt - ich weiß es nicht, ich habe nur die Ermutigung aufgegriffen, statt eines 7 Jahre alten Threads einen neuen zu machen. Und ich gehe davon aus, dass von offizieller Seite schon geschaut wird, was die Community-Überlegungen sind. Streng genommen ist das auch schon meine Spekulation.

Comment: Kann/sollte man denn hier noch Antworten posten, oder ist der Zug schon abgefahren?

Comment: @akuzminykh: ich denke: das Logo ist immer noch unverändert, also kann man hier noch Antworten posten. Jedenfalls habe ich ansonsten nicht wahrgenommen, dass irgendwas eingetütet wurde und "unaufhaltsam unterwegs" ist.

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from earlier today: [Custom German Language design and logo - Information gathering](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1697/8844) :)

Comment: Update: [New site design launched](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1752/8844) (which includes a redesigned "de" favicon!)

Answer (score 7):

Hier kommt zunächst kein eigener Vorschlag, bloß ein kurzer Gedankengang.

Das neue Logo sollte einem internationalen Publikum als Symbol der deutschen Sprache erkennbar sein, denn dies ist ein FAQ für deutsche Sprache.

Glyphen, die nur in der deutschen Sprache vorkommen, etwa das ß, sind vielen nicht bekannt.
Wer GermanSE explizit aufsucht, kennt es aber sehr wahrscheinlich, weshalb ich keine generellen Einwände gegen ß, ä, ö oder ü habe.

Anders sieht es mit Buchstaben in Fraktur oder Kurrent aus, oder was schriftgeschichtlich sonst so in der Requisitenkiste schlummert.
Dagegen habe ich zwei Einwände:

1. Um es auf die Spitze zu treiben: die erkennen die meisten jüngeren Deutschen heute nicht, geschweige denn, dass sie sie lesen könnten.
   Eine Verbindung zur deutschen Sprache ist rein geschichtlich, und bei den meisten Leuten nicht gegeben.
   Wenn die Verbindung denn gegeben ist, dann basiert sie meist nicht auf sprachgeschichtlichem Interesse, sondern auf einer sehr stereotypen Vorstellung vom „Deutschtum“.
2. Die Verbindung von Fraktur etc. zu diesem SE ist (typo)grafisch, nicht sprachlich.
   Wir befassen uns aber hauptsächlich mit deutscher Sprache, nicht mit deutscher Typografie.
   Es gibt hier zurzeit nur 33 Fragen, die überhaupt mit *typography* gekennzeichnet sind.

Aus diesen Gründen bin ich gegen eine Verwendung eines Frakturbuchstaben o. ä. als neues Logo.

Answer (score 6):

Die Seite für Spanisch, [Spanish Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/), hatte ursprünglich ein *ES*-Logo: [image], aber in [diesem Strang](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/13538) hat die Gemeinschaft ein neues Logo gewählt, basierend auf dem Buchstaben *ñ:*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Das sieht immer noch aus wie ein Beta Logo, aber es war ziemlich schnell erledigt.

Genauso wie das *ñ* charakteristisch ist für die spanische Sprache, ist es das Eszett (ß) für die deutsche Sprache. Wenigstens für mich, als Niederländer...

Weil wir wahrscheinlich ein oder mehrere Jahre auf ein volles Design warten müssen, können wir inzwischen dieses Logo benützen:

[image]

(oder eine etwas deutschere Schriftart)

Comment: Ja, das ß ist nur im Deutschen zu haben. Ich bin hauptsächlich skeptisch wegen der Nähe  ß - β (kleines Beta) - auch wenn der Strich nach unten raus nur im Beta ist.

Comment: Man könnte ja dieselbe Ligatur verwenden, die auf den Straßenschildern in Berlin zu finden ist.

Comment: Und vielleicht eine rote Sprechblase verwenden, damit es sich besser von den vielen anderen Sites abhebt.

Comment: ... wie https://craftcms.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Eine ansprechende Form vorausgesetzt, ist der einzige Nachteil des *ß*, den ich sehe, dass die Schweizer (und Liechtensteiner) es nicht nutzen.

Comment: Rot hatte ich nur angedacht, weil die Farbe in allen sechs Flaggen (D,A,CH,LU,BE,LI) vorkommt.

Comment: Ich fände es eigentlich gar nicht schlecht, wenn alle Sprach-SEs ein mehr oder weniger einheitliches Logo hätten, an dem man eben gleich erkennt: "Das ist eine Sprach-SE". Vielleicht wäre ein Umlaut (großes Ä) besser geeignet als das ß.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: das kleine ä sehe ich häufiger als große Änderungen. Ansonsten wäre das natürlich praktisch, wenn "Sprache-SE"s erkennbar wären. nur ist z.B. Englisch bereits "ausgeschert".

Comment: @Janka Das hätte meine Stimme. – Daß die Schweizer im Lauf des 20. Jahrhunderts das *ß* abgeschafft haben, ist für mich kein Argument gegen die Verwendung als Logo. Denn schließlich heißt das umgekehrt, daß es die längste Zeit auch Teil der schweizerischen Schreibung war.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ich halte wenig von historischen Argumenten im Bezug auf Sprache. Die Nutzer, die die Zeit vor der Schweizer *ß*-Abschaffung bewusst erlebt haben, dürften sich an einer Hand abzählen lassen. Mit einem ähnlichen Argument können wir auch das lange *s (ſ)* wählen, da es ja die längste Zeit Teil der deutschen Schreibung war.

Comment: Das ß sieht einem kleinen beta aus dem griechischen Alphabet zum verwechseln ähnlich, und weckt daher eher Assoziationen zu Physik, Geometrie oder Altgriechisch.

Answer (score 4):

Ich wäre wenn Sonderbuchstabe und kein Eszett dann eher für ein ä:
(Schriftart habe ich noch keine hübsche gesucht, mach ich später)

[image: einmal Fett und einmal nicht so fett]

Die Idee mit "Rot ist in allen Landesflaggen mit Deutsch als Amtssprache" aufgreifen, bin ich eher für rote Schrift auf (weißem) Grund.

Das ö erinnert mich zuerst an Österreich, bei denen rote Balken die dominierende Farbe ist, analog die Schweiz, wo rot alles umrahmt. Und bei der Deutschland-Flagge ist das rot zwar in der Mitte, jedoch von Schwarz und Gelb umrahmt, somit sehe ich keine Verwechslungsgefahr. (Bsp für DACH: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-A-CH)

Einzig das "Rote Kreuz" hat ein ähnliches Muster (da Schweiz-invertiert).

Warum das ä?
Weil - zumindest in Deutschland - viele mit "Häh?" ihr (akustisches) Nicht-Verstehen ausdrücken. Und ich das bei mancher Frage auch :-o.

[Edit:] Und "....äh..." ist (in Deutschland) auch so eine Standard-Antwort/ Füllwort. Da ist nun ein "h" erforderlich - finde "Einzelbuchstabe" bei allen Vorschlägen besser. [/Edit]

Kein ö, weil für mich ö = Österreich.

das ä im bisherigen Blau:

"inkscape default sans-serif":

[image: inkscape sansserif]
[image: inkscape in klein]

Bahnschrift:

[image: in Bahnschrift Fett & normal]

Amiri:

[image: Amiri Fett & normal]

Comment: Das linke ä sieht zumindest auch sehr freundlich aus.

Comment: Das mit dem "hä?" hat mich überzeugt!

Comment: Das Zeichen »ä« gefällt mir sehr gut, die Farbe Rot hingegen gefällt mir gar nicht. Ich bin hier eher für das bisherige Hellblau.

Comment: Das »ä« finde ich auch sehr passend. Bei der Farbe würde ich ein dunkleres Blau nehmen. Ich habe mal zwei Schriften herausgesucht, die ich als schön und angemessen empfinde: [Walbaum Antiqua](https://www.typografie.info/3/Schriften/fonts.html/walbaum-antiqua-r10/) und [Melior](https://www.typografie.info/3/Schriften/fonts.html/melior-r618/). Die sind aber leider nicht kostenfrei und ich weiß nicht, ob das dann mit SE vereinbar ist.

Comment: @akuzminykh: ich habe den von mir verstandenen Status quo in der Frage aktualisiert. Damit scheiden kostenpflichtige Schriftarten wohl aus, eine angelehnte Grafik ist nicht ausgeschlossen. Falls eine eigene Antwort unpassend scheint, kann ich einen anderen optischen ä-Vorschlag vom Kommentar gerne reinnehmen.

Comment: `ä` ist nicht spezifisch für die deutsche Sprache, sondern existiert zum Beispiel auch im Schwedischen Alphabet.

Comment: Das sieht aus wie das Logo der Band "Die Ärzte": https://www.google.com/search?q=die+%C3%A4rzte+logo :D

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\definecolor{SE}{HTML}{62B0DF}%
\begin{document}
\tikz{
     \node[fill=SE,text=white] { $\mathfrak{\ddot{o}}$};
       }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mir gefällt das irgendwie. Es wirkt... freundlich? Wobei ich auch noch anmerken will, dass die eigentlichen *Lords of Umlauts* die Finnen sind und somit das ß doch repräsentativer wär...

Comment: @miep Kommt auf die Definition an, immerhin schreiben die _ü_ als _y_.

Comment: *Ich bin mir nicht sicher, wie man dem Umlaut das Rund wegnimmt (und ob es sein muss).* – TeXs Mathe-Frakturen sind sicherlich nicht die beste Wahl für diese Anwendung, da sie mit einem ganz anderen Ziel gemacht wurden. Wir müssen auch darauf achten, dass das ganze auf 16×16 funktioniert. Aber als Skizze reicht es zunächst.

Comment: Ich mag am ö, dass das Ding wie ein Smilie mit offenem Mund aussieht. Passt zum Thema Sprache.

Comment: Ein Fraktur-ö müsste aber Häkchen haben, keine Punkte.

Comment: wenn es ein einzelner Buchstabe sein soll, dann eher D für deutsch oder ß als Original des deutschen Alphabets

Comment: Das Zeichen »ö« hat eine semantisch große Nähe zu »Österreich«, daher würde ich es eher nicht nehmen. Besser wären »ä« oder »ß«. Aber die Idee mit der Frakturschrift gefällt mir sehr gut, und auch die Farbe ist angenehm.

Answer (score 2):

> **Frage 2:** Inwiefern ist die German.SE-Community per Planung darin eingebunden?

Ich habe bei SE angefragt, welchen Einschränkungen wir unterliegen. Wie es weiter geht, hängt dann von der Antwort sowie dem Ergebnis der Abstimmung hier ab. Es kann sein, dass wir genau das bekommen können, was die überwiegende Mehrheit möchte. Es kann sein, dass nur eine zweite Abstimmung unter Berücksichtigung dieser Einschränkungen Klarheit bringen kann.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Entwurf]

Das ist ein Fraktur-*G;* links eine klassische Form; rechts etwas moderner. *G* für *German (Language).*

Vorteile:

- Der einzelne Buchstabe nutzt das quadratische Format gut aus und die Details sollten auch bei kleiner Auflösung nicht verloren gehen.
- *G* wird weniger mit Deutschland assoziiert als *D* oder *De* und schließt damit die übrigen deutschsprachigen Länder weniger aus.
- Die kalligrafische Natur der Fraktur passt eher zum Thema Sprache als eine schlichte Serifenlose (die eher zu technischen Themen passt). Vergleiche auch das Logo und Design für English Language and Usage:

  [image: English Language & Usage]

Nachteile:

- Basiert auf der englischen Bezeichnung der deutschen Sprache.
- Gerade im deutschen Sprachraum kann Fraktur negative Assoziationen wecken. Andererseits ist es auch keine [Schaftstiefelgrotesk](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebrochene_Grotesk) und auch sonst wenig »kantig«.
- Nur Eingeweihte werden die linke Variante als *G* erkennen, dafür ist sie optisch runder. Andererseits stellt sich die Frage wie sehr die Identifikation des Buchstabens wichtig ist. Die folgenden Logos sind für Uneingeweihte auch nicht leicht zuzuordnen (insbesondere in der kleinen Variante):

  [image: Arduino]
  [image: Bricks (Lego)]
  [image: Buddhism]
  [image: CiviCRM]
  [image: Hinduism]
  [image: Vegansim & Vegatarianism]

  (Auflösung im Quellcode bzw. Alt-Text.)

Comment: hmmm... als uneingeweihter bei einem Großteil der SE seiten, würde ich raten:
1. Mathe? 2. Lego 3. Seefahrt (ist das ein Steuerrad?) 4. Geometrie? 5. Irgendeine Sprache die nicht auf lateinischen Zeichen beruht 6. absolut kein Plan...

Comment: Ja, das mit dem Erkennen für uneingeweihte scheint wohl doch nicht so relevant zu sein.

Comment: @miep: Siehe meinen Edit.

Comment: Ich bin gegen ein G, das sagt wenig über die Sprache. Ein D mit der gleichen Schrift finde ich geeignet.

Comment: @c.p. Verstehe ich nicht: wieso sagt G(erman) weniger über die Sprache als D(deutsch)?

Comment: @Arsak weil man Englisch bräuchte. Sieht man das Logo, so denkt man an das, was schon miep im ersten Kommentar hier erwähnt.

Comment: For these sites, the symbols are very clear. But you should think of it as referenced from our designed logos. Are *they* all clear? Does the Server Fault logo mean anything to many people? Arduino uses an infinity symbol in their logo, Lego is pretty clear, the Dharma Chakra is a major part of Buddhism, we have express permission to use the [CiviCRM logo](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/why-not-use-the-civicrm-emblem-icon/31#31), Hinduism uses the "Om" a symbol directly connected to their religion, and the enclosed v is recognized in the vegan/vegetarian community.

Comment: That said, with the exception of the Lego block and the CiviCRM logo, they're all Unicode characters in the same font. I don't have an answer to whether any of these options are possible at this point but I strongly urge y'all to give us *an* option that is a simple Unicode symbol in our standard font. We're much more likely to implement something simple than something that requires code to create. And, unfortunately, just because we did something in the past, things are very different now... so don't assume that there's any precedence for fancy things.

Comment: You know who else used Fraktur? The nazis. In France, it's kept a bit of a bad taste. I'm surprised that it this feeling isn't present in Germany. I don't think it's a good idea to use it to represent German internationally.

Comment: @Catija: None of the suggestions actually requires code to create (the code used by C.P. is probably so others can easily adapt it). At worst, you’ll have to use a different font. Also what is your standard font for logos?

Comment: @Gilles: I am [quite aware](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/8691/2594) of the history and associations of fraktur and I mention this potential problem in my answer. However, it’s not that black and white. Using [blackletter grotesques](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebrochene_Grotesk) for everything certainly invokes a nazi association. Using a single, little angular letter in a logo is something that is quite common in the German language area and also internationally – e.g., roughly half the German beer brands use it. (Sidenote: You know who abolished Fraktur in Germany? The nazis.)

Comment: @Gilles: PS: *In France, it's kept a bit of a bad taste.* – In another illustration of why context and details matter: [One of the largest French newspapers](https://www.lemonde.fr/) uses a blackletter typeface in its logo. (It’s not “pure” fraktur, but then it’s only six different characters anyway and most of the audience won’t be sensitive to such details.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I read *Le Monde*. I don't associate its logo with Fraktur. It's  a blackletter typeface where the letters are clear to someone who can't read Fraktur. To me, it's a newspaper title typeface, not a pre-WWII-Germany typeface.

Comment: @Gilles Regarding *Le Monde* sounds like double standards (which non expert would be able to recognize the non-originality of the logo if typed with fraktur?), also based on a regional and, as of your last comment, even personal perception, being also intentionally nonfactual, e.g. pre-WWII? (fraktur = version typographique de l'alphabet latin apparue en Allemagne au début du *XVIe siècle*)

Comment: @c.p. Yes, my comment is about my perception (which I believe, but cannot prove, is shared by many people in Europe). Symbols are about perception, not about facts. The swastika also has a long history before nazism, but a few years of nazism has made it unacceptable throughout Europe.

Comment: @Gilles: in fact the Nazis were the ones who FORBID blackletter to be used in Germany. Search for "Schwabacher Judenlettern" or "Bormann-Erlass". Neonazis use that typeface primarily because they are as clueless and uneducated about history as they are politically (which is why they are nazis in first place).

Answer (score 1):

Auf die Anregung von Takkat, was Botanisches zu nehmen, fällt mir in erster Linie das ein

[image]

Hat für mich irgendwie mehr Wiedererkennungswert als ein Ginko.

Comment: Das ist ein Chinakohl. Was habt ihr alle mit China?

Comment: @janka Autsch. Botanik-Nachhilfe: Das ist ein deutscher Spitzkohl (*Brassica oleracea*), aus dem man Sauerkraut macht. Chinakohl ist oben rund.

Comment: So geht das natürlich, nicht! Aber vielleicht ja als icon? (Sofern Bergdeutsche sich da inkludiert sehen)

Comment: Wollt ihr nicht lieber gleich Grünkohl nehmen? Halt, da werden wir noch für das Land der Hipster gehalten. (Die futtern das Zeug roh! Igitt.)

Comment: Dachte erst das ist Hopfen..

Comment: ... hätte aber SUPER gepasst :D:D:D

Answer (score 1):

Meine einzige Beta-Erfahrung sah so aus, dass ein kompletter Satz an Dekoration (Großer Hintergrund für die Startseite, Logo, Pfeile für die Bewertungen, Formen von Medaillen) geliefert wurde und dann kommentiert werden konnte.

Ich finde etwas Botanisches netter als einen germanischen Buchstaben, und fände ein Eichenblatt ganz nett; vgl. das Heine-Gedicht [Zur Telelogie](https://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/pommeren/Gedichte/HeineNachlese/teleolog.htm) und die Rückseite der alten Pfennig-Münzen und der deutschen kupferfarbenen Cents.

> Und man macht aus deutschen Eichen // Keine Galgen für die Reichen

Mangels künstlerischer Begabung verzichte auf einen Grafik-Vorschlag, das sollte aber auch bei kleiner Auflösung erkennbar sein.

Comment: Das Eichenlaub hatte ich erst im Sinn, dann aber verworfen, weil es seit dem 18. Jahrhundert als deutsches Nationalsymbol gebraucht wird... Österreicher, Schweizer und andere deutschsprechende Nationen mögen das Eichenlaub vielleicht unpassend finden. Dann noch eher die Linde, deren Blatt aber unspektakulär ist.

Comment: Das Gedicht ist fantastisch!

Comment: Die Eiche ist leider ein National- oder nationalistisches Symbol Deutschlands. Ich würde es vermeiden, solche Assoziationen zu wecken. Das Heine-Gedicht ist nett, aber im Logo-Kontext irrelevant, weil es kaum jemand kennen dürfte, geschweige denn den Bezug dazu erkennen würde.

Answer (score 1):

Eine Möglichkeit (vorgeschlagen von Janka in einem Kommentar) wäre, eine Eszett zu verwenden, wie es auf Berliner Straßenschildern zu finden ist, also eine Ligatur aus langem S und Z mit Unterschlinge: **ſʒ**; siehe auch folgendes [Foto auf Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#/media/Datei:Berliner_Strassenschilder.jpg).

1. Das Eszett an sich ist charakteristisch für die deutsche Sprache und hat einen hohen Wiedererkennungswert.
2. Das Eszett in dieser spezifischen Form kann nicht mit einem griechischen Beta **β** verwechselt werden.
3. Die Ligatur **ſʒ** verweist auf die Sprachgeschichte, auf Sprachwandel, auf das Verhältnis von Laut und Schrift (siehe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#History).

Der letzte Punkt und die Tatsache, daß das lange S und das Z mit Unterschlinge in der Gegenwart keine Verwendung mehr finden, mildern in meinen Augen das Problem, daß das Eszett als Symbol den Schweizer Sprachraum exkludieren könnte. Ohnehin wurde das Eszett bis ins 20. Jahrhundert hinein, also die längste Zeit, auch in der Schweiz verwendet.

Das Eszett als Logo würde als Symbol fungieren. Symbole haben oft historische Bezüge und müssen nicht die Gegenwart reflektieren.

Answer (score 0):

Ich schlage ein kleines fettes Antiqua-**ö** in weißer Farbe auf rotem Grund vor.

[image: ö128]
[image: ö32]
[image: ö16]

(Exakter Font egal, das Beispiel ist in *Liberation Serif Bold*.)

- Es hat einen hohen Wiedererkennungswert.
- Man kann es auch in Verkleinerung sehr gut erkennen.
- Es sieht wie ein sprechender Smiley aus. Passt zum Thema.
- Das ö wird auch in der Schweiz und in Liechtenstein benutzt.
- Rot kommt in den Flaggen von D/A/CH/LU/BE/LI/IT vor. Jedenfalls passender als Hellblau.

Klar, das ö wird auch in anderen Sprachen verwendet. Ich denke aber, dass die meisten SE-Nutzer Umlaute doch am ehesten mit Deutsch in Verbindung bringen und nicht mit Schwedisch oder Türkisch. (Wobei das Türkische diese Notation ja aus dem Deutschen übernommen hat.)

Comment: Hellblau war die Farbe, die nicht "graduierten" Seiten (wie unserer) reserviert war. Wusste nicht, dass man die Farbe wählen darf.

Comment: Hilfe! Das Logo darf man ändern, nicht aber die Farbe? Wer zum Teufel denkt sich solchen kleinteiligen Unsinn aus?

Comment: Mh, so haben es Spanisch (und weitere mehr) gemacht.  Schau auch die Liste neuer Logos am Ende der Antwort von Wr*...ft. (Wollte keine abenteuerliche Farbeänderung machen, dafür finde ich Hellblau sehr doof).

Comment: Naja, es funktioniert auch mit Hellblau. Und wenn dann der Grad auch irgendwann verschenkt wird, ist es ja nur ein einfacher Handgriff, auf Rot umzustellen.

Comment: ö sterreich war meine erste Assoziation. Nicht ganz getroffen imho

Comment: wäre eher für das ä - kommt von "häh?" und sagen alle, die zwar Deutsch können aber nix verstehen ... so wie manche Frage^^

Answer (score 0):

Die Auswahl eines möglichst deutschen Buchstaben erscheint mir schwierig. In Vertriebskreisen gibt es das Kürzel  D-A-CH, was aus den Auto-Länderkennzeichen für Deutschland, Österreich und Schweiz zusammengesetzt ist und zufällig einem Substantiv entspricht. Wird das allgemein verstanden, und kann man das so symbolisieren, dass keine Verwechslunsgefahr mit einem griechischen Lambda Λ besteht?

Answer (score -2):

Um ungewollte Assoziationen und gängige Klischees zu vermeiden, die eine Frakturschrift mit sich bringen könnte, können wir uns auch eine [Kurrentschrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent) überlegen. Damit lägen wir optisch auch nahe an unserer großen Schwesternseite English Language.

[image] einfaches großes D

[image] initiales großes D

Anmerkung: [das große G](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1525/23) ist in der Kurrentschrift recht langweilig (aber besser zu entziffern). Ich würde das D bevorzugen.

Beweggründe, weshalb eine heute zwar nicht mehr gebräuchliche und von den meisten Leuten nicht mehr lesbare deutsche Kurrentschrift keine schlechte Wahl ist für eine Seite über die deutsche Sprache gibt folgendes Zitat:

> Die deutsche Kurrentschrift etablierte sich ab dem 16. Jahrhundert als die übliche Verkehrsschrift im **gesamten deutschen Sprachraum**. Insbesondere in Österreich etablierte sich Kurrent auch als Amts- und Protokollschrift. In der Schweiz war Kurrent bis zum Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts als Verkehrs-, Amts- und Protokollschrift gebräuchlich.<sup>[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift)</sup>

In Deutschland haben die Nazis 1941 die Kurrentschrift und daraus abgeleitete Sütterlin-Schrift verboten.

Comment: Ich muss gestehen - ich habe das "E" von Englisch.SE nie wirklich nur als E wahrgenommen. Irgendwie schien da noch was zu sein, das ich nicht entziffern kann. Entsprechend würde ich das D hier auch nicht erkennen. Wirkt auf mich eher wie ein ... so ein griechicher Buchstabe, nur die Schriftart bei Wikipedia widerspricht meiner Erinnerung :-)

Comment: Why not go for sth different, like https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/sign-language_2014335#term=language&page=1&position=52

Comment: Für mich null assoziiert. Für Aussenstehende wahrscheinlich ebenso wenig zugänglich.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu es ist nicht zu erwarten, dass irgendjemand noch Kurrentschrift beherrscht. Für ein Icon bewegen wir uns aber kongruent mit anderen SE-Seiten, deren Logo ebenfalls nicht immer leicht zu erschließen ist. Das muss ja auch gar nicht sein. Ich halte wegen der klischeehaften Verwendung Fraktursatz für sehr problematisch (es sei denn, wir wollen mit   genau diese Klischees erfüllen).

Comment: @Takk OK, das verstehe ich und bzgl. Fraktur stimme ich zu. Ich persönlich finde aber schon, dass ein Logo zumindest halbwegs erschließbar sein sollte. Insofern sind die erwähnten Vorbilder aus meiner Sicht heraus nicht so interessant für uns, auch wenn damit vielleicht interessante oder gewagte Entwürfe ausscheiden würden.

Comment: Ja, bitte keine Fraktur, aber ob das die Alternative sein kann?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Wenn ich das richtig sehe, hat english.stackexchange `et` als Zeichen, es ist also tatsächlich so, dass "da noch was ist", neben dem e.

Answer (score -3):

Zur Vervollständigung und zur Abstimmung hier noch ein G-Initial in Kurrent:

[image]

Answer (score -8):

Unser Icon sollte sich deutlich von den anderen Icons abheben und etwas mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun haben. Somit scheiden alle geografischen oder nationalen Symbole aus. Ebenso möchte ich darauf hinweisen, dass der Buchstabe **ß** nicht in allen deutschsprachigen Regionen vorkommt, man würde damit z.B. die Schweiz ungewollt ausschließen.

Ein Symbol, das mit dem bedeutendsten deutschen Dichter [Johann Wolfgang von Goethe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Wolfgang_von_Goethe) in Verbindung gebracht wurde ist das Blatt der Ginkgo Pflanze, die Goethe in einem [Gedicht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Goethe_Ginkgo_Biloba.jpg) beschrieben hatte:

> Dieses Baums Blatt, der von Osten
>   Meinem Garten anvertraut,
>   Giebt geheimen Sinn zu kosten,
>   Wie’s den Wissenden erbaut,
>
> Ist es Ein lebendig Wesen,
>   Das sich in sich selbst getrennt?
>   Sind es zwei, die sich erlesen,
>   Daß man sie als Eines kennt?
>
> Solche Frage zu erwidern,
>   Fand ich wohl den rechten Sinn,
>   Fühlst du nicht an meinen Liedern,
>   Daß ich Eins und doppelt bin?

Das Ginkgo-Blatt ist auch als Symbol von einigermaßen hohem Erkennungswert:

[image]

---

*Wem der Hintergrund fehlt, weshalb der Ginkgo etwas mit Goethe zu tun hat, sei auf die [Seite des Weimarer Ginkgo Museums](http://www.ginkgomuseum.de/content/ginkgomuseum/goethe-und-ginkgo/) verwiesen. Ich denke mir sowas ja nicht unüberlegt aus...*

Comment: Ich denke, dass nur ein verschwindender Teil des Publikums das Ginko-Blatt verstehen wird.

Comment: Ich denke, dass man den Ginkgo eher mit China in Verbindung bringt.

Comment: Wenn das heute auf einer EDV-lastigen Seite keiner (mehr) kennt, dann macht es natürlich wenig Sinn. Ich finde ein Ginkgo-Blatt halt hübscher als die diversen Silhouetten.

Comment: Und dann wäre da noch Gardening SE, die gleichzeitig den Beta-Status abgelegt haben...

Comment: Ich finde das Gedicht schön, ich kannte es bisher nicht - und schon der Inhalt macht mir deutlich - es hat mit der deutschen Sprache nur soviel zu tun, als das Goethe drüber schrieb. Jedenfalls verbinde ich weder Goethe noch die Sprache mit dem Baum

Comment: @Takkat: Das Interesse Goethes an dem Gingobaum und die erfolgreiche Zucht ändert nichts daran, dass auch die genannte Quelle von einer Vorliebe "exotischer Pflanzen" spricht - somit kann ich verstehen, dass Gingko nicht gerade als "europäische, gar deutsch(sprachige) Pflanze" wahrgenommen wird. Da bin ich nun zwar schlauer (G-G), verneine trotzdem den Wiedererkennungswert für "Deutsch".