# German Language site design and logo — Final draft

Tags: discussion, design

Here are the final 3 options for the logo based on [the feedback received so far](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/german-language-site-design-and-logo-draft). As always, colours can be modified if you believe there is a better choice. I will also post each of these as an answer below so that they can be voted on individually.

[image: Logo of ß and SS overlapping]

[image: Logo of ß/SS separated by a slash]

[image: Logo of ß and ? combined]

I also made updates based on your feedback and can present the final versions of the main site and the meta site.

**Main site:**
[image]

**Meta site:**
Note that the colours have been muted here compared to the previous version.
[image]

Additionally, here are the images selected for the 404, error, and captcha pages.

**404 page:**
[image]

**Error page:**
[image]

**Captcha page:**
[image]

Once we have decided on a logo, this theme will begin to be implemented into code. I look forward to getting that out to you very soon!

Danke!

Comment: Is it a 4th option to keep the current logo? If yes, it should be possible to vote for this, as well.

Comment: Would be nice to get an answer on this.

Comment: As for the 404, error and captcha pages, I'd suggest adding (or at least linking) some info or context: the curious pictures are likely to make users (like me) want to find out more.

Comment: Hey marquinho, these were originally a suggestion by Wrzlprmft. You can see their post containing an explanation here: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1710/53099

Comment: Hey! I would add the current logo as another option to vote for, if you don't mind. Just let me know, if you have reservations.

Comment: @kplsn: Thanks, I remember reading that. I wasn't referring to your current post above. My suggestion would be to add info/reference/a link *to the 404 page* (etc.) *once it goes live*, so that a user seeing the pictures isn't left wondering what they're about. Images are slightly harder to google than phrases. (A link to Wrzlprmft's post, f.i., could do the job). Sorry if I was unclear! :)

Comment: I also second @JonathanScholbach's query about the current logo – would it be an option? Does something speak against putting it to a vote?

Comment: I just added the current logo (https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1742/15393) Let me know if there is a problem with this.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, we can certainly keep the current logo if we do not like any of the alternatives offered. No problem at all. :)

Comment: Hi Marquinho, oh that's a good idea. I can consider a way to integrate that into those pages. Thanks :)

Comment: I think the issue is that logos were suggested with asking ideas from community for brain storming

Comment: Update: [New site design launched](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1752/8844)

Comment: @DiscoSt.Ives - Hope you see this comment :) I like the fun and quirky new design of the error/captcha pages. I'd like to reiterate my suggestion though: How about **providing a reference for the images used** (Max und Moritz etc.)? You could f.i. (1) add a *caption*, (2) some *alt-text*, or (3) make the image a *hyperlink* to some external resource. As of now, there is no hint on the [404 page](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/999999) ([meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999999)) that would help a curious user learn about the pictures (or visually impaired users).

Answer (score 6):

This is the current logo. (Note, that the designer has not yet specified whether it is an option to stick to it or whether there are reasons we have to pick a new logo.)

[image: current logo of german.SE]

Comment: I don't share your general conservatism when it comes to the design, but I think the new 'options' (we have only been presented a single option that can really be considered) are really terrible, as I've already pointed out in the draft post. Maybe having a better designed version of just "De" is the way to go.

Comment: I have come to peace with the idea that we are just going to have a new design. I still wanted to specifically put the current logo to a vote, because I am having doubts about the new logo. Of the ideas presented in the process, the `ß?` idea was the only one I found acceptable at least, but I am still not sure that it would be an improvement. @idmean

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback. I was happy to have been able to put hard work into this design and am looking forward to delivering you something that you like. I will be keeping the concept of the current logo (as shown here), with only very minor changes. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Tut mir leid, aber ich kann mich mit dem einzig verbliebenen Vorschlag nicht anfreunden. Ich habe minutenlang gerätselt, was es wohl bedeuten soll, möglicherweise auch wegen der sofortigen Assoziation mit dem Logo von Klosterfrau Melissengeist. Ich sehe immer noch zwei verschlungene gotische Torbögen und kein Eszet als erstes. (Die farblich gemischte Version hat mich auf den Trichter gebracht, aber der Erkennungswert eines guten Logos sollte "farbenblind" sein.)
Eine aufgelockerte Form [wie ursprünglich als erstes vorgeschlagen](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1706/16948) hat für mich mehr Erkennungswert und Assoziation zu einem Herzen.

Die Diskussionen in [einem (dem ursrprünglichen?) vorangehenden Strang](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/german-language-site-design-and-logo-draft) habe ich versucht nachzuvollziehen, aber sie scheinen mir trotz [fast dreijähriger Diskussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1516/bedarf-w%C3%BCnsche-vorschl%C3%A4ge-an-ein-neues-logo-f%C3%BCr-german-se/1534) wenig repräsentativ. Und der Bedarf für das Logo scheint nicht von einer Mehrheit gesehen zu werden.

Das Eszet ist wohl ein Alleinstellungsmerkmal für die deutsche Schrift, wird aber in der Schweiz seit fast hundert Jahren nicht mehr benutzt. Damit ist eine der Inklusionsvoraussetzungen bedauerlicherweise nicht erfüllt!

Bevor mich in die Diskussionen einzulesen schwebte mir ein Logo in Art der [DACH](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-A-CH) vor. Natürlich fehlen dann einige unserer Nachbarländer, so wie auch Liechtenstein (nebenbei bemerkt das einzige direkt aus dem HRR hervorgegangene heute noch existierende deutschsprachige Land) und im Prinzip sogar Russland, Kasachstan u.v.a.m. Aber gibt es Widerspruch, wenn Englisch stellvertretend mit der bekannten amerikanisch-britischen Flaggenkombinationen angezeigt wird (wobei der Union Jack genau genommen selbst als Kombination ja auch noch zwei nicht-englische Sprachen einschließt)?

Fazit: Das [hier vorgestellte Design](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/german-language-site-design-and-logo-draft) sagt mir zu. Aber für das Logo habe ich weiter oben nur zwei insgesamt negativ bewertete und einen meiner Meinung nach unleserlichen Entwurf gesehen. Da gehe ich schon eher, wie auch oben vorgeschlagen, mit der Idee, das alte zu behalten – anstatt hier ein klassisches Bespiel für Verschlimmbessern zu schaffen.

Die Sommerferien sind im Übrigen nicht die beste Zeit, um einen ausgeglichenen, demokratischen Konsens zu finden.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another logo option based on the feedback from [this comment](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/german-language-site-design-and-logo-final-draft/1738?noredirect=1#comment4218_1740).

[image: logo option with question mark symbol in gold]

Comment: Infrequent visitor of this community; I came to see whether this suggestion had been made. I find it much easier to "decode" what the consituents of the logo are supposed to be. In the pure black version, I read it as a `?`+`B` with a teaspoon of `k`. The desired `ß` association only came much later. On second thought: I guess the current glyph form does not the best job of "selling" the character.

Answer (score 2):

Mein Vorschlag:
Das ist das ganz normale (kleine) scharfe S aus der Schriftart Calibri. Man erkennt an dieser Form schön, dass das scharfe S eine Ligatur aus einem langen und einem runden S ist. Sowohl das mittlerweile ausgestorbene lange S als auch das scharfe S (das in Deutschland, nicht aber in Österreich, Eszett heißt, obwohl es keine S-Z-Ligatur sondern eine S-S-Ligatur ist) waren einst typisch für die Verschriftlichung deutscher Sprache. Heute ist es nur noch das scharfe S.

Über die Farben kann man gerne diskutieren, da sind gerne auch andere Kombinationen möglich.

[image: Vorschlag für Logo]

Comment: Digentlich Ess-Zett, weil eine zeit lang auch -sz- für das scharfe s geschrieben wurde. Dabei entspricht z viel mehr ç, bzw. ς, so wie з ζ.  Das Lange S hat idealer Weise einen Schwung unten, sonst erkennt man Ess kaum. Sútalin-Schrift wäre vielleicht ganz suesz.

Answer (score -6):

Logo option #3

[image: logo number 3 with the ß merged with a question mark]

Comment: I wonder if the question-mark part of this logo could be filled in (or maybe partially filled, or outlined) with a similar golden color to the one used in the other proposed logos, to make it easier to see that it's a combination of the ß and ? characters...?

Comment: @V2Blast: You mean like the bottom row [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1706/2594)?

Comment: Out of the three given options, this is the best (by being the only acceptable one). I am not sure though, if it is better than the current logo.

Comment: The shape of lower bowl looks out of balance. It should touch the baseline and be more pronounced. That would also allow for more space around the dot.

Comment: Katie has posted an alternate version based on my feedback above as an option [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1741/8844).

Comment: @misterben: By the "lower bowl", I assume you mean the bottom half of the right side of the ß character? (Do you mean that it should look a bit more like [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#/media/File:S-sharp-s-Lucida-Sans.svg), with the curve sticking out to the right more, and curving back up after it touches the baselines?)

Comment: @misterben: While the lower bowl can be bigger, I would consider it within the range of what is typical for *ß.* As for the baselines, the logo has to handle [overshoots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overshoot_(typography)) as well as alignment with the dot of the question mark. While the logo may look tilted if you focus on the baseline scaled high up, these choices make sense if you don’t (which corresponds to regular viewing). By contrast, what you suggest would probably look misaligned.

Comment: I'm going to repeat my criticism from the previous draft post: The logo doesn't make any sense to me. Not knowing what it was supposed to be, it looked more like a symbol from a South Asian language. (Reverse Google search does indeed bring up Bengali and Odia characters.) I don't think I would ever associate it with the German Language. It should be reconsidered.

Comment: Ich kann nicht erkennen, was das darstellen soll. Erst als ich die farbige Version gesehen habe, habe ich gesehen, dass es eine Ligatur aus einem scharfen S und einem Fragezeichen sein soll. Aber warum baut man ein Fragezeichen in das Logo ein? Welchen Sinn soll das haben? Und warum um alles in der Welt sollte man ein Fragezeichen mit einem scharfen S zu einem Zeichen verschmelzen wollen? Das macht für mich überhaupt keinen Sinn. Wenn es sonst keine anderen Auswahlmöglichkeiten gibt, würde ich vorziehen, beim alten Logo zu bleiben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ich kann deinen Einwand hier und anderswo nach der Umsetzung nachvollziehen, aber wenn man die Historie verfolgt, sieht man dass das schon einmal gut ankam [Custom German language design and logo information gathering](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1697/custom-german-language-design-and-logo-information-gathering). Vielleicht hättest du deine Einwände auch auf Englisch einbringen sollen. Ich bin zu selten hier, mir ist das neue Design zwar aufgefallen, aber Heute hat mich mal interessiert wann das zustande kam.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Ich habe erst sehr spät mitbekommen, dass das Design geändert wird, und ich habe meinen Vorschlag daher auch erst gemacht, als die meisten Entscheidungen schon getroffen waren. Im übrigen finde ich es auch ein wenig seltsam, wenn sich ein Haufen deutscher Muttersprachler in einer Fremdsprache darüber unterhält, was mit einer Seite passieren soll, die genau ihre eigene Muttersprache zum Thema hat.

Answer (score -9):

Logo option #1

[image: logo number 1 with the ß and ss overlayed on top of each other]

Comment: I don't think, we should have _ss_ in the logo.

Comment: To elaborate @JonathanScholbach’s comment: The abbreviation SS is strongly associated with [this organisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutzstaffel) in Germany and therefore usually shunned. For example, it is not issued on license plates (see e.g., [this article (in German)](https://www.spiegel.de/auto/aktuell/verbotene-kfz-kennzeichen-keine-nazi-nummernschilder-a-1025284.html)).

Comment: You're right, that makes a lot of sense and was an oversight on my end. The reason I tried it in the logo was due to some feedback around it in the previous post. We can certainly scrap the idea in this case.

Answer (score -10):

Logo option #2

[image: logo number 2 with the ß and ss separated by a diagonal line]

Comment: Same problem with _ss_.